# parsing solution file using powershell

Tags: regex, powershell

I have a solution file that includes some projects inside and I'd like to delete some of them using PowerShell.
The aim is to delete a block of text that contains a string (let's say "abcxyz") starting with "Project" and ends with "EndProject" in the next line (or more than that).

For example:

```
Project("{1111-2222-FFFF-3333}") = "AutoRun", "..\generate\Infra\generate\generate.csproj", "{999999-UUUUUU-GGGGGG-ABCDEFGH}"
EndProject
Project("{5555-2222-FFFF-3333}") = "SetupSec", "..\generate\Setup.csproj", "{999999-UUUUUU-GGGGGG-ABCDEFGH}"
EndProject
Project("{4444-2222-FFFF-3333}") = "Common.Fyyy", "..\generate\Infra\Common\Common.csproj", "{999999-UUUUUU-GGGGGG-ABCDEFGH}"
EndProject
Project("{9999-2222-FFFF-3333}") = "Command.Console", "..\generate\Path\Console.csproj", "{999999-UUUUUU-GGGGGG-ABCDEFGH}"
EndProject
Project("{7777-2222-FFFF-3333}") = "Infra.GUI", "..\..\generate\GUI.csproj", "{999999-UUUUUU-GGGGGG-ABCDEFGH}"
    ProjectSection(ProjectDependencies) = postProject
        {AAAA-2222-FFFF-3333} = {999999-UUUUUU-GGGGGG-ABCDEFGH}
    EndProjectSection
EndProject
```

In the example above, I'd like to remove projects contains the string "Infra" in any case.
Is there a simple way of doing it using **PowerShell Regex**?
(deletion should be done to entire solution file from *Project* to *EndProject*)

Thanks,

Shai.

Answer (score 2):

I came here looking for a similar solution.  What I did was create this powershell function.  It may just be a good jumping off point where you can tailor to your more specific requirements, but it works for me. Enjoy...

```
    function Remove-SourceControl() {

        param (
            [string]$sourceFilePathname
        )

        $tempFile = New-TemporaryFile
        $filterOn = $false
        $fileVersionCorrect = $false

        $backupFile = "$sourceFilePathname (backup)"
        Copy-Item $sourceFilePathname $backupFile

        $rowIndex = 1

        Get-Content -Path:$sourceFilePathname | ForEach-Object {
            if ($_ -like "*Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 12.00*" ) {
                $fileVersionCorrect = $true
            }
            if ($fileVersionCorrect -eq $true) {
                if ($_ -like "*TeamFoundationVersionControl*") { $filterOn = $true }
                if (!$filterOn) {
                    Write-Output $_ | Out-File -FilePath:$tempFile -Append
                }
                if ($filterOn -and $_ -like "*EndGlobalSection*") { $filterOn = $false }
            } else {
                Write-Output $_ | Out-File -FilePath:$tempFile -Append
            }
            $rowIndex++
        }
        if ($fileVersionCorrect -eq $true) {
            Copy-Item $tempFile $sourceFilePathname -Force
        }
        Remove-Item $tempFile
    }

    $path = "c:\some-folder-pathname"

    Remove-SourceControl "$path\MySoluton.sln"
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your actual file is consistent with the sample data, you can do this without needing to mess with regex at all:

```
Get-Content $ProjectFile -Delimiter 'EndProject' |
  Where-Object {$_ -notlike '*Infra*'} |
  Add-Content $NewProjectFile
```

That will break up the file into separate projects, and then filter out any of them that contain the string "Infra", and write the rest to a new file.

Comment: The actual file is not consistent with the sample data. Solution files are nasty

Answer (score -3):

Your question is "is there a simple way in Powershell" and the answer is: **No.**

Solution files are a nasty old format with various widely-separated parts that depend on each other. It is possible to edit them by hand but it is hard to get right and easy to get wrong.

If you simply want to delete some projects, open the file in Visual Studio, delete the projects, and save it.

If this question is to solve part of a larger problem, you should ask a new question, how to solve that larger problem.

Comment: The question says specifically "_The aim is to delete a block of text that contains a string (let's say "abcxyz") starting with "Project" and ends with "EndProject" in the next line_"; now how you read that as "delete visual Studio projects from powershell" only god knows

Comment: @ᴳᵁᴵᴰᴼ It is obvious to me, but if you don't see it, I guess you just don't see it.

Comment: I would tend to agree here.  Solution files need to be internally consistent, and just deleting references out can easily result in an inconsistent file that you may not even be able to open (or that will generate multiple "missing reference" errors).  You basically need to parse the files the same way that Visual Studio will to handle all the possibilities, which is a lot more complicated than regex + delete.

Comment: Guys, you can treat this as a regular text file and no a solution file. Is it possible or not (ignore the solution thing here, I'll do the rest...)

Comment: @ShaiO, I'm not going spend time helping you to hurt yourself! If you tell me what you are actually trying to do I can maybe help with that, but don't edit solution files with regular expressions. Just don't.

Comment: @Ben - OP didnt need a yes or no question, they needed something useful and your assertion is flatly incorrect (I've parsed solution files with powershell, and other answers have also shown its possible and not difficult to do in powershell).